# ddply stops with warning Error in str2lang(x) : <text>:2:0: unexpected end of input

Tags: r, plyr

## Question

I have the following code of `ddply` where the inside function works well with a single element `i` in `modelNames`. However, when I run the entire code in `ddply`, it gives me error:

```
Error in str2lang(x) : <text>:2:0: unexpected end of input
1:  ~ 
   ^
```

Do you have any idea what part of code may cause the issue?

## Current Code

```
  t <-  
        modelNames %>% 
        ddply('model', function(i){
          print(i)
          colnames <- names(d)
      
  dep <- 
    models %>%
    chain.filter('dep') %>%
    filter(model == i) %>%
    filter(dep == 1) %>%
    .$variable
  
  indep <- 
    models %>%
    chain.filter('dep') %>%
    filter(model == i) %>%
    filter(indep == 1) %>%
    .$variable

  
  base <- 
    Reduce(intersect, list(indep, colnames)) 


  interaction <-
    expand.grid(base, base) %>% 
    mutate(
      interaction = paste0(Var1, '*', Var2)
    ) %>% 
    .$interaction 
  
  interaction <-
    Reduce(intersect, list(indep, interaction)) 
  
  indep <- 
    c(base, interaction)
  
  eq <- 
    paste(indep, collapse = ' + ') %>%
    paste(dep, ., sep = ' ~ ') %>%
    as.formula  
  
  s <-
    lm(eq, d) %>%
    summary(.) %>%
    .$coefficient %>%
    as.data.frame
  
  r <-
    lm(eq, d) %>%
    summary(.) %>%
    .$r.squared
  
  n <- nobs(lm(eq, d))
  
  t <- data.frame(
    model = i,
    variable = rownames(s),
    estimate = s[, 1],
    se = s[, 2],
    group = 'Estimates'
  ) %>% 
    chain_stars(asterisk = c('', '', '\\textsuperscript{*}', '\\textsuperscript{**}')) %>% 
    rows_insert(tibble(variable = 'rsqr', estimate = as.character(easy.round4(r)), se = NA, group = 'Overall')) %>% 
    rows_insert(tibble(variable = 'obs', estimate = as.character(prettyNum(n, big.mark = ",", scientific = F)), se = NA, group = 'Overall'))  %>% 
    gather(state, value, -c(group, variable))
  
  t
}, .progress = 'text')
```

Comment: `plyr` has been retired long back, you should switch to `dplyr`. It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).